# Use different Classes in Java(Android)?

Tags: android

When should I create a completely new Java Class File and when should I just start a new public class in the Main activity if I don't need a new UI or anything like that?

I am asking right now because my toturial for using recyclerViews is telling me to create a new File for the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you really. Either option works.
Personally, if it's a complicated adapter I'll use a new file.